# How to add the summation of a matrix to all the diagonal elements of the matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add the summation of a matrix to all the diagonal elements of the matrix.

I have the code to get the diagonals of the matrix and the code for the summation of a matrix. How to I isolate the diagonals of each matrix?

Here is my current code:

```
diag = np.diag(A)
A_sum = A.sum()
```

Example:

Original matrix:

```
[[0  1  2]
 [3  4  5]
 [6  7  8]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[36  1  2]
 [ 3 40  5]
 [ 6  7 44]]
```

The summation of all the values of the original matrix is 36. I would add 36 to the diagonal values of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.diag_indices_from`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices_from.html) to get the diagonal indices of an array, then just add to those elements:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)  
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])

idx = np.diag_indices_from(A)
A[idx] += np.sum(A)

print(A)
# [[36  1  2]
#  [ 3 40  5]
#  [ 6  7 44]]
```